# Graphic-Tikz in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ domain=0:10, samples=100,
axis lines*=left, xlabel=Rent, ylabel=\empty,,
height=6cm, width=10cm,
xtick={0}, ytick=\empty,
enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
]
\addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-3:3] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=orange!20, draw=none, domain=-3:-2] {gauss(0,1)}     \closedcycle;
\node[coordinate, pin={VAR}] at (axis cs: -2, 0){};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and I want to add:

- The y axis on the 0
- The word "Var" below the x axis
- Inside the "brown" part I want to write a small text

I want something similar than this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please complete your code snipped so, that we can copy it and test in our PC, e.g. add `\documentclass{...}` used packages etc...

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for your advice. I've done it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not very sure, what you like obtain ... so far I guessing that something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
height=6cm, width=10cm,
domain=0:10, samples=100,
axis lines*=center,
xlabel={Rent}, ylabel=\empty,
extra x ticks={0},
xtick={0}, ytick=\empty,
enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
]
\addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=-3:3] {gauss(0,1)}    \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=orange!20, draw=none, domain=-3:-2] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
\draw (-2,0) -- (-2,{1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((-2)^2)/(2))});
\node[anchor=north] at (-2,0) {VAR};
\node[anchor=south,pin=120:small text] at (-2,0) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The brown area is small, so probably there will not be enough place to write it inside. Maybe the solution is to use label (pin) outside of it (as is shown on above image).

**Edit:** added line between brow and blue area is hard coded.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I exactly wanted it!. The only thing that I need is to plot a line between the blue and brown part. I've tried to do it by myself but I couldn't. Do you know how to do it?